# Nginx + Tornado ( + curl): Inflate gzipped POST request

Tags: file-upload, curl, nginx, tornado, http-compression

I have setup a server (well... two servers, but I don't think that is too relevant for this question) running Tornado (version 2.4.1) and being proxied by Nginx (version 1.4.4).

I need to periodically upload `json` (basically text) files to one of them through a `POST` request. These files would greatly benefit from gzip compression (I get compression ratios of 90% when I compress the files manually) but I don't know how to inflate them in a nice way.

Ideally, Nginx would inflate it and pass it clean an neat to Tornado... but that's not what's happening now, as you'll have probably guessed, otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question **:-)**

These are the relevant parts of my `nginx.conf` file (or the parts that *I think* are relevant, because I'm pretty new to Nginx and Tornado):

```
user  borrajax;
worker_processes  1;

pid    /tmp/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    access_log  /tmp/access.log  main;
    error_log   /tmp/error.log;

    # Basic Settings

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;    
    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types        application/json text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/x-icon image/bmp;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;

    upstream web {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    upstream input {
        server 127.0.0.1:8200;
    }

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

            proxy_pass http://web;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 81 default_server;
        server_name input.localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

            proxy_pass http://input;
        } 
    }
}
```

As I mentioned before, there are two Tornado servers. The *main* one is running on `localhost:8000` for the web pages and that kind of stuff. The one running on `localhost:8200` is the one intended to receive those `json` files) This setup is working fine, except for the Gzip part.

I'd like for Nginx to inflate the gzipped requests that come to `localhost:81`, and forward them to the Tornado I have running on `localhost:8200` (inflated)

With the configuration like this, the data reaches Tornado, but the body is still compressed, and Tornado throws an exception:

```
[E 140108 15:33:42 input:1085] Uncaught exception POST 
  /input/log?ts=1389213222 (127.0.0.1)
  HTTPRequest(
      protocol='http', host='192.168.0.140:81', 
      method='POST', uri='/input/log?&ts=1389213222', 
      version='HTTP/1.0', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', body='\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00', 
      headers={'Content-Length': '1325', 'Accept-Encoding': 'deflate, gzip', 
      'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Host': '192.168.0.140:81', 'Accept': '*/*', 
      'User-Agent': 'curl/7.23.1 libcurl/7.23.1 OpenSSL/1.0.1c zlib/1.2.7', 
      'Connection': 'close', 'X-Real-Ip': '192.168.0.94', 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
   )
```

I understand I can always get the request's `body` within the `post()` Tornado handler and inflate it manually, but that just sounds... dirty.

Finally, this is the `curl` call I use to upload the gzipped file:

```
curl --max-time 60 --silent --location --insecure \
    --write-out "%{http_code}" --request POST \
    --compressed \
    --header "Content-Encoding:gzip" \
    --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
    --data-binary "$log_file_path.gz" \
    "/input/log?ts=1389216192" \
    --output /dev/null \
    --trace-ascii "/tmp/curl_trace.log" \
    --connect-timeout 30
```

The file in `$log_file_path.gz` is generated using `gzip $log_file_path` (I mean... is a regular Gzip compressed file)

Is this something doable? It sounds like something that should be pretty straight forward, but nopes...

If this is is something not doable through Nginx, an automated method in Tornado would work too (something more reliable and *elegant* that having me uncompressing files in the middle of a POST request's handler) Like... something like Django middlewares or something like that?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already calling `json.loads()` somewhere (Tornado doesn't decode json for you so the exception you're seeing (but did not quote) must be coming from your own code); why not just replace that with a method that examines the `Content-Encoding` and `Content-Type` headers and decodes appropriately?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I remove the Content-Type header in the curl call, it keeps happening. Even if it was that, shouldn't I be seeing an inflated body in the exception?

Comment: I didn't say change the request; I said to change your code to decompress the data you're receiving.  Since the json decoding is already in your code instead of the framework (if you are getting an exception from tornado instead of your own code, please post the traceback), there's no benefit to putting the decompression in some magical "middleware".

Comment: So, what you're recommending is get the request.body in the Tornado handler and inflate that with my own code? I kind of wanted to avoid that, and have Nginx (or Tornado) inflating the request in a transparent way.

Comment: Yes.  You're already calling json.loads(request.body) in your code, right?

Comment: I am, I am... What I wanted to do is having request.body decompressed automatically. The issue is not json, the issue is that the body is still gzipped when it reaches json

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to have Nginx or Tornado automatically expanding the body of the POST request, so I went with what Ben Darnell mentioned in his answer. I compress the file using gzip and POST it as a part of a Form (pretty much as if I were uploading a file).

I'm gonna post the bits of code that take care of it, just in case this helps someone else:

**In the client (a bash script using curl):**

The path (absolute) to the file to send is in the variable `f`. The variable `TMP_DIR` points to `/tmp/`, and `SCRIPT_NAME` contains the name of the bash script trying to perform the upload (namely `uploader.sh`)

```
zip_f_path="$TMP_DIR/$(basename ${f}).gz"
[[ -f "${zip_f_path}" ]] && rm -f "${zip_f_path}" &>/dev/null
gzip -c "$f" 1> "${zip_f_path}"
if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [[ -s "${zip_f_path}" ]]
then
    response=$(curl --max-time 60 --silent --location --insecure \
                    --write-out "%{http_code}" --request POST \
                    "${url}" \
                    --output /dev/null \
                    --trace-ascii "${TMP_DIR}/${SCRIPT_NAME}_trace.log" \
                    --connect-timeout 30 \
                    --form "data=@${zip_f_path};type=application/x-gzip")              
else
    echo "Attempt to compress $f into $zip_f_path failed"
fi
```

**In the server (in the Tornado handler):**

```
try:
    content_type = self.request.files['data'][0]['content_type']
    if content_type == 'application/x-gzip':
        gzip_decompressor = GzipDecompressor()
        file_body = gzip_decompressor.decompress(
                        self.request.files['data'][0]['body'])
        file_body += gzip_decompressor.flush()
    else:
        file_body = self.request.files['data'][0]['body']
except:
    self.send_error(400)
    logging.error('Failed to interpret data: %s',
                  self.request.files['data'])
    return
```